# How do I add a column in dynamodb using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I was going through documentation of cloudformation for creating a dynamodb.I am able to create a table with a key but I can't find any way to create an item in the table using the template.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation is used to create infrastructure (eg Databases, EC2 instances, networks).

It cannot be used to define data to be loaded into a database. For that, you would need to trigger some code that calls the DynamoDB API and loads data.

If you wish to trigger this action from a CloudFormation template, use a **Custom Resource** to trigger an AWS Lambda function. Then, code the Lambda function to load the data into the DynamoDB table.